# Kafka Consumer is getting few (not all) old messages (that was already processed earlier)

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer

We have topics with retention set as 7 days (168 hours). Messages are consumed in real-time as and when the producer sends the message. Everything is working as expected. However recently on a production server, Devops changed the time zone from PST to EST  accidentally as part of OS patch.

After Kafka server restart, we saw few (not all of them, but random) old messages being consumed by the consumers. We asked Devops to change it back to PST and restart. Again the old messages re-appeared this weekend as well.

We have not seen this problem in lower environments (Dev, QA, Stage etc).

Kafka version: kafka_2.12-0.11.0.2

Any help is highly appreciated.

Adding more info... Recently our CentOS had a patch update and somehow, admins changed from PST timezone to EST and started Kafka servers... After that our consumers started seeing messages from offset 0. After debugging, I found the timezone change and admins changed back from EST to PST after 4 days. Our message producers were sending messages before and after timezone changes regularly. After timezone change from EST back to PST, Kafka servers were restarted and I am seeing the bellow warning.

This log happened when we chnaged back from EST to PST : (server.log)
[2018-06-13 18:36:34,430] WARN Found a corrupted index file due to requirement failed: Corrupt index found, index file (/app/kafka_2.12-0.11.0.2/data/__consumer_offsets-21/00000000000000002076.index) has non-zero size but the last offset is 2076 which is no larger than the base offset 2076.}. deleting /app/kafka_2.12-0.11.0.2/data/__consumer_offsets-21/00000000000000002076.timeindex, /app/kafka_2.12-0.11.0.2/data/__consumer_offsets-21/00000000000000002076.index, and /app/kafka_2.12-0.11.0.2/data/__consumer_offsets-21/00000000000000002076.txnindex and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)

We restarted consumers after 3 days of timezone change back from EST to PST and started seeing consumer messages with offset 0 again.

Comment: Do you use `consumer group` ?

Comment: Yes, we have 2 consumers and both use the same consumer.id. I just reviewed the code and consumer application is not closing the KafkaConsumer as part of application shut down. However, after consuming the messages we are committing it. The duplicate/old messages appear once in a while we restart consumer application.

Comment: Using Kafka (0.11.0.2) and Java Client API version is 1.0. enable.auto.commit = false and programatically comitting -> consumer.commitSync();

Comment: @user1114134 did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

As on Kafka v2.3.0
You can set

```
    "enable.auto.commit" : "true",// default is true as well
    "auto.commit.interval.ms" : "1000"
```

This means that So after every 1 second, a Consumer is going to commit its Offset to Kafka or every time data is fetched from the specified Topic it will commit the latest Offset.

So no sooner your Kafka Consumer has started and 1 second has elapsed, it will never read the messages that were **received** by the consumer **and committed**. This setting does not require Kafka Server to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you will restart the program before you `Commit` new offsets.

> **Managing offsets**
>
> For each consumer group, Kafka maintains the committed offset for each partition being consumed. When a consumer processes a message, it doesn't remove it from the partition. Instead, it just updates its current offset using a process called committing the offset.
>
> If a consumer fails after processing a message but before committing its offset, the committed offset information will not reflect the processing of the message. This means that the message will be processed again by the next consumer in that group to be assigned the partition.
>
> **Committing offsets automatically**
>
> The easiest way to commit offsets is to let the Kafka consumer do it automatically. This is simple but it does give less control than committing manually. By default, a consumer automatically commits offsets every 5 seconds. This default commit happens every 5 seconds, regardless of the progress the consumer is making towards processing the messages. In addition, when the consumer calls `poll()`, this also causes the latest offset returned from the previous call to `poll()` to be committed (because it's probably been processed).
>
> If the committed offset overtakes the processing of the messages and there is a consumer failure, it's possible that some messages might not be processed. This is because processing restarts at the committed offset, which is later than the last message to be processed before the failure. For this reason, if reliability is more important than simplicity, it's usually best to commit offsets manually.
>
> **Committing offsets manually**
>
> If ‍`enable.auto.commit` is set to false, the consumer commits its offsets manually. It can do this either synchronously or asynchronously. A common pattern is to commit the offset of the latest processed message based on a periodic timer. This pattern means that every message is processed at least once, but the committed offset never overtakes the progress of messages that are actively being processed. The frequency of the periodic timer controls the number of messages that can be reprocessed following a consumer failure. Messages are retrieved again from the last saved committed offset when the application restarts or when the group rebalances.
>
> The committed offset is the offset of the messages from which processing is resumed. This is usually the offset of the most recently processed message plus one.

From [this article](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/messagehub114.html#consuming_messages), which I think is very helpful.

Comment: We are calling consumer.commitAsync(); (we have logged "before commit" and "after commit" log message. And this is being logged properly).  Also, we are not seeing consistently the old messages after everytime we restart consumer application. Occasionally we do see offset going back to 0 and start seeing old messages.

Comment: can you append your code to question? I want to see your code.